# CSS3 How use style only for first div in div?

Tags: css

Code:

```
<div class="BlockContent">
    <div class="input">
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
        <input type="text" name="username">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <input type="password" name="username">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.BlockContent .input:first{
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.BlockContent .input{
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Tell me please how change line css `.BlockContent .input:first` that only first `div.input` have style `margin-top: 16px;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer here, but a better solution. Rather than padding an empty, non-semantic `div`, it would be better to add padding or margin on an existing element. For example, you could set top inner padding on the `input` container, or top margin on the input itself.

Comment: yes, thanks - i use margin but content is empty. you right, me need use padding in parrent block.

Answer (score 3):

You’re looking for `:first-child`

```
.BlockContent .input:first-child {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `.BlockContent .input:first-child { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You just missed one word i think.

```
.BlockContent .input:first-child{
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```